# Aura Console Warnings in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning, partner-communities, lightning-community, warning

In my lightning community (Community Template: Partner Central Spring ’18) I see the following warnings:

1. `WARNING: $A.eventService.addHandler: Unknown component with globalId 'undefined'. Does this component exist?  @aura_proddebug.js:33153...`
2. `WARNING: unused configs for 2;a: 2;a/*[0]  @aura_proddebug.js:33153...`

It happens on standard pages as well as on my custom pages/components.
Is there something I can do with it?